# Android Log class: is it insecure?

Tags: android, security, logging

I heard at a few places that the Android Log class could open up security problems from things like disassemblers. How true is this?

Comment: Voting to close as that question is not a real question. Log is nothing more than outputting information to the log, so that it can be pulled in from `adb logcat`. Think of it as a placeholder to hold log information. The only security problem is if you divulge in there by *your own doing* sensitive information then yes, you have a security issue. It can be useful as a modern-day equivalent of BASIC's PRINT$ statement to see the flow of the code, nothing more.

Comment: Have you looked into this yourself and what resources have you found to suggest there is a security problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should not log sensitive details like user logins etc in your `LogCat`. Another improvement in JellyBean is that other applications can now NOT see `LogCat`'s from your application. You should watch this to get an idea on [Security in Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPJENzweI-A).